# How to import text file that will supersede data in existing column using vba

Tags: vba, file, text, import

From VBA I need to import a text file, transform it to whole numbers, and load it into column A. It has to clear the current data set and load the new one. It also has a formula in B1, =SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1)), that sums column A which is variable length. I'm going to run the VBA file over and over each time with a new set of numbers with variable rows.
I then want to write out the sum in B1 to a text file that I can read from another program.

So far when I import the text file in creates a sheet. I have yet to figure out how to just clear column A and load the new data set in sheet 1 that will have the formula to sum the variable length column A.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, show us what code you have now with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the text file with the data that you are trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Until you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), these two pieces may give you some directions:

To clear column A:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(1).select
Selection.ClearContents
```

And for paste data, something like this:

```
For iLoop = 0 To UBound(ArrayOfTextToPaste)
   Range(ColumnToPaste & iFirstRowToPaste + iLoop) = ArrayOfTextToPaste(iLoop)
Next iLoop
```

Again, provide us with an example, and we can try to fill the gaps.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)), a place to start to dig.